# Inverse image of an endomorphism of a finite index subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

The following has appeared in page 63 of Combinatorial Group Theory notes by Charles. F. Miller.

I am trying to understand the proof of the following theorem.

**Theorem(Malcev)**: Finitely generated residually finite groups are Hopfian.

In part of the proof says the following, which I can't understand:

"Suppose that $G$ is finitely generated and residually finite. Let $\psi:G\rightarrow G$ be an epimorphism. Let $H$ be a subgroup of finite index, say $n=[G:H]$. Then $\psi^{-1}(H)$ is again a subgroup of finite index $n$ in $G$..."

I understand the fact that $\psi^{-1}$ is a subgrgroup of $G$. But why $[G:\psi^{-1}(H)]=n$?

Comment: This follows from ${\rm Ker}(\psi) \le \psi^{-1}(H)$ and $G/{\rm Ker(\psi) }\cong G$.